# Can't import Bootstrap 5 variables into SASS module while importing from Bootstrap 4 works fine

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, module

We have a React project with SASS modules. I have to upgrade Bootstrap in the project from version 4 to version 5. There are some files (*.module.scss) with following CSS classes:

```
.active {
        @extend .mt-1;
    }
```

To extend the mt-1 class Bootstrap class and other classes Bootstrap is imported like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

This works with Bootstrap 4 but do not work with Bootstrap 5. The error says `SassError: The target selector was not found. Use "@extend .mt-1 !optional" to avoid this error.`. I tried with other CSS classes like .fw-bold and always get the same error. What's wrong? How to import variables in Bootstrap 5? I cannot import entire Bootstrap `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` because I will get error `Selector ":root" is not pure` - :root selector cannot be used in SASS module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! For Bootstrap 5 I had to import also `@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";`. This is how to import Bootstrap 5 to a SASS module (*.module.scss):

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

Now I am able to extend `@extend .shadow-sm;` and other classes.